# New function doesn't appear under App Service name list when creating a pipeline release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I add a function app to a Resource Group, but when I create the release pipeline, using "Deploy Azure Function App", the new function app doesn't appear in the "App service name" list. Sometimes it appears later, like after an hour. But right now I have one I created yesterday, and it still hasn't appeared, 12 hours later. I can see the other function apps in the Resource Group, just not the new one.

It looks like the same issue as this one: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-find-App-Service-name-azure-devops/1651959?q=app+service+name

I tried commenting, but that website gives an error. Come on, Microsoft...

Comment: Might be a caching issue at Microsoft's end. I'd report the issue at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues instead, and see if that helps. The linked ticket seems dead and forgotten, as it's 10ish months old.

Comment: OK. I created it here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17216

Comment: You can check you function app settings and state .Make sure if it's  available and has access . refer to  doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's normal for it to take 1-3 hours for the function app to show up in DevOps. But in my case there was a service degradation, which is why it took 20 hours.

I met with Azure support over this. There was an issue with their back end services that required some development work to fix.

Lately the function apps appear a lot quicker. Sometimes right away, other times it took a few hours.

Comment: If it helps you, you could accept it as answer. It could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Is there any source for this information? Meaning this is pretty much unacceptable behaviour and makes fluent deployments quite complex if you have to orchestrate infrastructure changes by this way beforehand.

Comment: Are you still seeing the issue? MS fixed/improved this, or at least they tried. I don't have a reference, other than the ticket in the op, only observations.